# Finding particular cities along your Path

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need your suggestion. I am creating a web application where I need to find if particular city's exist along my path. I am using google API to get direction along path,but it does not return the cities between.

For Example if I am travelling from A - > D  , I like to know whether C ->D exist along my path A - > D  . If I know the cities between A -> D , I can easily do that .But google API doesnt reveal that . Does any one have any other better suggestion . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of a city isn't very accurate, you'll need a LatLng for the city.

Based on a LatLng the method `isLocationOnEdge()` of the geometry-library allows you to determine if the LatLng(city) lies on (or is near) the polyline defined for a route:

```
google.maps.geometry.poly
  .isLocationOnEdge(LatLngOfCity,
                    new google.maps.Polyline({path:google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(response.routes[0].overview_polyline.points)}),
                    0000000001));
```

`response` has to be a directionsResult, the last parameter is a tolerance

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/DXCH8/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/DXCH8/)

Comment: HI @Dr.Molle, the solution you gave works for real time,But in my case I have thousands of routes or people who registered saying traveling from A to D and I want to iterate all of them to check this.Is there any other way ??

Comment: In this case you would need a server-side solution. Sounds as if http://luktek.com/Blog/2011-02-03-google-maps-routeboxer-in-php should work in PHP(haven't tested it), it should be possible to translate it to another language when needed.